# What does ValueError: Can not convert from <U76 to float64. mean?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying to grayscale and denoise images. Image files are originally TIF images. Previous version of this program had one large loop grayscaling then denoising and worked without error. I am trying to restructure it to grayscale and save as one loop and then start a new loop to denoise but now I get the error:

```
ValueError: Can not convert from <U76 to float64
```

Code is below. Can anyone please tell me what that conversion error means so I might try to fix it? I am not sure what is happening. Thanks!

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(originalDir):
for file in files:
    path = subdir + os.sep + file

    original = io.imread(path, plugin = 'pil')
    grayscale = rgb2gray(original)


    filename = f"{grayDir}/{file}_gray.jpg"
    io.imsave (filename, grayscale)


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(grayDir):
for file in files:
    path = subdir + os.sep + file

    noisy = img_as_float(path)

    Bilateral = denoise_bilateral(noisy, sigma_color= colorValue, sigma_spatial=spatialValue,
                                      multichannel=False)
    plt.imshow(Bilateral)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to load the image. This method needs the RGB image array,  not the path.

```
img_as_float(image, force_copy=False)
```

Parameters
`image : ndarray, shape (M, N[, 3])` - Input image, 2D grayscale or RGB.

try to load the image first:

```py
original = io.imread(path, plugin = 'pil')
noisy = img_as_float(original)
```